# c# find words in sequence in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

i have 2 `rich text boxes`. first text box contains the input and the second text box will display the output of found words

input:
my name is umer
my father name is waqar

output:

```
umer is found
my is found
name is found
is is found
father is found
my is found
```

the output is not as what i want. **i want an output like this below**:

```
my is found
name is found
is is found
umer is found
my is found
father is found
name is found
is is found
waqar is found
```

my code is:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("umer"))
            richTextBox2.AppendText("\numer is found");

            if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("my"))
            richTextBox2.AppendText("\nmy is found");

            if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("name"))
            richTextBox2.AppendText("\nname is found");

            if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("is"))
            richTextBox2.AppendText("\nis is found");

            if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("father"))
                richTextBox2.AppendText("\nfather is found");

            if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("waqar"))
                richTextBox2.AppendText("\nwaqar is found");
        }
```

Comment: i'm learning c# so i will be much more appreciated if someone would give simple and detailed solution

Comment: So you basically want `is found` after every word?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it you want to do with the inputs exactly ? (What's the rule for that seemingly random output that you wish to achieve)

Comment: i am just learning to write the found words as they appear in the input (in a sequence same as input sequence)

Comment: `if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains("waqar"))
                richTextBox2.AppendText("\nmy is found");` this doesn't make sense.  Why Append `my is found` if it contains waqar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you required :

```
 string[] words = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');       
 foreach (string searchString in words)
 {
      if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(searchString))
      {
         richTextBox2.AppendText(searchString + " is found.\n");
      }
 }
```

Comment: may be i am not be able to explain what i what :( i am trying to find the words and write them in richtexbox2. but i am not be able to do that in sequence.

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want. because i want to search whole paragraph and display the searched words in richtextbox2 if they exists in richtextbox1

Comment: @UmerWaqar - Hi See my edited answer. It Gives Output what you require.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `is found` after every word, you can replace your `if` list with:

```
var words = richTextBox1.Text.Split(' ');
richTextBox2.Text = String.Join(words, " is found \n");
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>you can use linq to get unique words :</strike>

```
string text = "my name is umer my father name is waqar";

var uniqueWords = text.Split(' ').GroupBy(x => x).Select(x=>x.Key);

foreach (var value in uniqueWords)
{
   richTextBox2.AppendText(value +" is found");
}
```

### UPDATE (As OP requirement is not uinque words):

```
var result= text.Split(' ');

foreach (var value in result)
{
   richTextBox2.AppendText(value +" is found");
}
```